# NUnit's [TestCaseSource] with multiple arguments like with MbUnit's [Factory]

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, mbunit

Is it possible to use NUnit's [TestCaseSource] attribute with more than one arguments? Here's my code (which is being migrated from MbUnit):

```cs
public IEnumerable<object[]> GetTestSwitchMultiItems()
{
    yield return new object[] { SwitchType.Sell, 0.94733, 
                       new SwitchSourceItem[] { new SwitchSourceItem(1176, 100, 50, SwitchSourceItem.QuantityType.TotalQuantity, SwitchType.Sell)}, 
                       new SwitchEquivalentItem[] { new SwitchEquivalentItem(415318955, 35, 25, SwitchType.Buy), new SwitchEquivalentItem(4348, 65, 45, SwitchType.Buy) } };

    yield return new object[] { SwitchType.Sell, 0.94733, 
                       new SwitchSourceItem[] { new SwitchSourceItem(1176, 100, 50, SwitchSourceItem.QuantityType.TotalQuantity, SwitchType.Sell)}, 
                       new SwitchEquivalentItem[] { new SwitchEquivalentItem(415318955, 15, 25, SwitchType.Buy), new SwitchEquivalentItem(4348, 25, 45, SwitchType.Buy), 
                                                    new SwitchEquivalentItem(430397879, 20, 15, SwitchType.Buy), new SwitchEquivalentItem(5330, 20, 85, SwitchType.Buy)} };
}

[Test, TestCaseSource("GetTestSwitchMultiItems")]
public void TestSwitchMultiItems(SwitchType switchType, double exchangeRate, SwitchSourceItem[] sources, SwitchEquivalentItem[] equivs)
{
    ...
}
```

You see, parameters are passed as an object[] in order to have more than one parameters in TestSwitchMultiItems. Should that work or must I instead use only one parameter in TestSwitchMultiItems(object[] parameters). Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `TestCaseSource` attribute with multiple arguments. In the example you give, you will see the test `TestSwitchMultiItems` run twice. I used NUnit on the following contrived test code. `TestSwitchMultiItems` runs twice, and the trivial `Assert` call in each test passes.

```cs
[Test, TestCaseSource("GetTestSwitchMultiItems")]
public void TestSwitchMultiItems(string switchType, double exchangeRate, object[] sources, object[] equivs)
{
   Assert.AreEqual("Sell", switchType);
}

public IEnumerable<object[]> GetTestSwitchMultiItems()
{
    yield return
       new object[]
       {
          "Sell", 0.94733, new object[] { new { a = 1176, b = 100, c = 50, d = 5, e = "Sell" } },
            new object[] { new { a = 415318955, b = 35, c = 25, d = "Buy", e = 4348, f = 65, g = 45, h = "Buy" } }
        };

    yield return
        new object[]
        {
           "Sell", 0.94733, new object[] { new { a = 1176, b = 100, c = 50, d = 5, e = "Sell" } },
            new object[]
            {
                new { a = 415318955, b = 35, c = 25, d = "Buy", e = 4348, f = 65, g = 45, h = "Buy" },
                new { a = 415318955, b = 35, c = 25, d = "Sell", e = 7348, f = 65, g = 45, h = "Sell" }
            }
        };
}
```

Comment: GetTestSwitchMultiItems should be a Static method.